# How Can I show the date in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I want the date to be sn at my  page, I used this fn to  the date using Javascript:

```
    function Return() 
        {
           var d = new Date();
           var n = d.();
           var to ="";

           if (n == 0)
            to = 'Sun';
           else if (n == 1)
            to = 'Mon';
           else if (n == 2)
            to = 'Tues';
           else if (n == 3)
            to = 'Wednes';
           else if (n == 4)
            to = 'Thurs';
           else if (n == 5)
            to = 'Fri'
           else if (n == 6)
            to = 'Satur';
           else
           alert('To is No');

          return to;

}
```

At the  page I used this line to call it, but it's not working:

```
    <input id="DateAndTime" type="text" value ="Return()"></input>
```

Do you know  can I display it on the  page? 
And if you know any better(but simple too) ideas for sing the date at  pages please inform me about it.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following.

Your javascript should look like below

```
    <script>
       function ReturnDay() 
    {
       var d = new Date();
       var n = d.getDay();
       var today ="";

       if (n == 0)
        today = 'Sunday';
       else if (n == 1)
        today = 'Monday';
       else if (n == 2)
        today = 'Tuesday';
       else if (n == 3)
        today = 'Wednesday';
       else if (n == 4)
        today = 'Thursday';
       else if (n == 5)
        today = 'Friday'
       else if (n == 6)
        today = 'Saturday';
       else
       alert('Today is NoDay');

        document.getElementById("DateAndTime").value = today;
    }
ReturnDay();
    </script>
```

and your html

```
 <input id="DateAndTime" type="text" value ="" />
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mr2rr/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [javascript date object.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

You could also use PHP using the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

Answer (score 2):

You can just call this function and it will set the date for you.

```
function SetDay() 
{
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var today ="";

    if (n == 0)
        today = 'Sunday';
    else if (n == 1)
        today = 'Monday';
    else if (n == 2)
        today = 'Tuesday';
    else if (n == 3)
        today = 'Wednesday';
    else if (n == 4)
        today = 'Thursday';
    else if (n == 5)
        today = 'Friday'
    else if (n == 6)
        today = 'Saturday';
    else
       alert('Today is NoDay');

   // Notice this set the day in your field with the id "DateAndTime"
   document.getElementById("DateAndTime").value = today;

   // Or if you want to set it via jQuery
   // $('#DateAndTime').val(today);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not rely on client-side code to produce any time related data.

That is, unless you don't care, then by all means rely on whatever on earth the client device's time is set to ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this inline code if you want:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var d=new Date();
document.write(d);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See W3 schools for almost all web-dev needs: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: Great I like this function ~~
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a more elegant way of replacing your `if-else` statements:

```
function dayOfWeek() {
  var now = new Date();
  var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  return dayNames[now.getDay()];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems that you want a date input field, possibly you can use something existing.

The jquery UI library has a datepicker, which might just what you are looking for:

```
$( "#yourinputid" ).datepicker();
```

[See this link to the jquery UI page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function SetDayOfTheWeek(){
    var d=new Date();
    var weekday=new Array(7);
    weekday[0]="Sunday";
    weekday[1]="Monday";
    weekday[2]="Tuesday";
    weekday[3]="Wednesday";
    weekday[4]="Thursday";
    weekday[5]="Friday";
    weekday[6]="Saturday";

    var today = weekday[d.getDay()];
    document.getElementById("DateAndTime").value = today;
}

SetDayOfTheWeek();
```

Comment: Thanks lot :) Are you sure it's working? Coz  it didn't work with me.